# Java string replace regex for invalid characters in a phone number

Tags: java, regex, phone-number

I'm trying to write a regex to replace all invalid characters in a phone number:

Example phone numbers:

- +36 00 211 1111 -> +36002111111
- +49 03 691 4193 -> +49036914193
- +36 00 211 1111 -> +36002111111
- 06 78 90 12 34  -> 0678901234

The regex should allow the "+" sign only if it's the first character in the string and the rest only numeric types `[0-9]`

This is my current regex:

```
phone = phone.replaceAll("[/(?<!^)\+|[^\d+]+//g]", "");
```

Comment: How does your current regex fail? Can it be that those **outer** `[..]` serve no obvious purpose? (If Java's regex is anything like the regular ones, they make *everything* inside a 'one character' set.)

Comment: I'd use `.replaceAll("^(\\+)|\\D+", "$1")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this one: `[^\d+]|(?!^)\+`

```
phone = phone.replaceAll("[^\\d+]|(?!^)\\+", "");
```

- `[^\d+]` matches a character that's not a digit or `+`
- `(?!^)\+` matches `+` characters that are *not* at the start of the string

In your current regex, `[/(?<!^)\+|[^\d+]` is just a character class (so it matches a single character, and `+` makes it repeat that character class, and then your pattern matches the *literal* `//g]` string. So, bad syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The result can be achieved with a regex without any lookarounds. Capture the plus at the start of the string to be reinserted with `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern and just match all non digits.

```
^(\+)|\D+
```

In Java:

```
.replaceAll("^(\\+)|\\D+", "$1")
```

Pattern details:

- `^(\+)` - group 1 capturing a literal plus at the start of the string
- `\D+` - one or more chars other than digits.